# Unlock this question, please. Perhaps allow locks to timeout

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

I encountered this question via an organic search result in Google. Can a mod please unlock it so that I can upvote it?

[How can I make Safari show the URL when I hover over a link?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16759/how-can-i-make-safari-show-the-url-when-i-hover-over-a-link)

The question has been locked for **7 months**, and the system doesn't trust me that my upvote would be not genuine. A user's combined reputation should be a good indicator that they're not messing around.

This leads to a **feature request**: provide the mods an option to expire the lock after *n* days.

[image]

Comment: I unlocked it (and undeleted the Ultimate Status Bar answer because that extension does exactly what the question was asking is da bomb). An auto-unlock for mods to set would be a cool feature IMO.

Answer (score 5):

You can flag a post for unlocking as well as post on the meta as you did. Thanks for showing up and helping to up vote good content.

There is a feature to lock posts for a time period and then unlock them, however this post had answers that were continually vandalized by a bot performing anonymous edits. It devalued the review queue so I locked the post.

If the bot comes back, we will have to lock it - the good news is there are enough votes for this post to rise to the top of just about any search.